# How can I pass data to a partial view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to do crud operations using a modal but I don't know how to access the specific data needed to operate on the selected Item.

```
@model IEnumerable<Category>
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Categories</h1>
<button><a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Create">Add Category +</a></button>
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Category Name
      </th>      
      <th>
        Display Order
      </th>      
      <th>
        Created Date
      </th>
      <th>
        Edit Category
      </th>
      <th>
        Delete Category
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var obj in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@obj.Name</td>
        <td>@obj.DisplayOrder</td>
        <td>@obj.CreatedDateTime</td>
        <td>
          <button><a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id">Edit Category</a></button>
        </td>        
        <td>
          <button  onclick="add()"><a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@obj.Id">Delete Category</a></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<partial name="_viewpartial"/>
```

I have here my Category view rendering a table with table rows for each data point in the database. I am able to access the ID in the loop allowing me to delete items in my Delete Action method. But how can I use that specific ID in my modal partial view, which is outside the loop, to call the Delete Action method?

Here's my partial view

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this category?</p>
//selected category will have its name as the disabled input value next line
    <input value="Category" disabled/>
    <div class="confirmation">
      <button><a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a></button>
      <button><a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Delete">Delete</a></button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Note: I'll be using Javascript to handle the module popping up

Please try to be clear. I am very new to ASP.NET

Edit: Currently I have the Delete button going to the Delete action method but of course, I want only the delete button in the modal to do it. So the delete button in the table will only serve to bring up the modal with the `Add()` function when I can get the modal working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass data to a partial view client-side.  That all happens server-side.

Since this is all happening client side, it would be best to just do this with javascript and then call your controller via AJAX passing in the right record Id, or using a hidden field as [Amit Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11574318/amit-ranjan) suggested.

However, another approach that isn't as clean, but simpler since you're new to asp...

1. Move the partial view to inside the loop and pass the data to it like this:  `@await Html.PartialAsync("_viewpartial", @obj.Id)`
2. Wrap the partial view above in a `<div style="display:none">`.  You could even give it an ID to make it easy to find... `<div id="record_@obj.id" style="display:none">`
3. You now have a hidden dialog for every record in your table.  Now you just have to make it visible when someone clicks the delete button.  To do that, add an on-click event to the button:  `onclick="$('#record_@obj.id').show();"`

Comment: Hmmm, this creates a modal for every element. I guess that's why it isn't optimal. Don't know much about AJAX or Jquery, so thanks! This was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a workaround here. In that modal popup html put a hidden input and fill it from the table's delete button onclick event (js). For that you need to hook a client script to that table's button.I can see you already have an add() attached on its click event.

### HTML

```
<td>
  <input type='hidden' value="@obj.id" />
  <button onclick="add();">
    <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Modal" asp-route-id="@obj.Id">Delete Category</a>
  </button>
</td>
```

### Code

```
function add()
{
  var hiddenVal =  $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val();
  var modalHidden = $("#mhidden").val(hiddenVal);
  return false;
}
```

IDK whats the actual purpose of add, but here i am using the same name to find the id and append it to. Here mhidden one more hidden field in your modal's html. Now on modals delete button call async /ajax call to delete the id saved in #mhidden